# How can I browse for services through WMI?

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-service

At first I wasn't able to connect to the other computers with wbemtest.
Now, after following this instructions: http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enableWMI.aspx
I can run the following WQL query on it:

```
Select * From Win32_Process
```

But the following query only gets me the "Access denied" error message:

```
Select * From Win32_Service
```

What do I need to do in the remote machine in order to enable the local browse for the remote's services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after hours and hours of wondering lost I found this pdf document that tells how UAC interferes with your set of permissions and how can you fix that:
http://www.solarwinds.com/documentation/apm/docs/APMWMITroubleshooting.pdf

In my case, the registry key didn't existed, but you could create it easily.

[image]
That key from above does the trick (after all else is set of course!), 
Cheers!

Comment: This fix is described as being only relevant to computers in a Workgroup. This MSDN document explains more:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826699(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As a remote user, you need the `SC_MANAGER_CONNECT` privilege.

See [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Service Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I think this provides more insight on the set permissions required, but since I had those set correctly set already the problem wasn't solved, 
Sorry :(